# Mysql adding and subtracting different column without duplicating values

Tags: mysql, database

So, Im trying to make a database which allows to automatically add and subtract product quantity when customer order or I order on the supplier. This is my code:

```
select p.productid, p.productname,p.price,
p.quantity + (ifnull(sum(s.quantity),0) - ifnull(sum(o.quantity),0))as 
quantity  
from product p 
left join wholesale.supply s on p.productname = s.productname 
left join wholesale.order o on p.productname = o.productname 
group by p.productname order by quantity
```

This is the output without any order:

```
productid     productname        price     quantity      
   6            Sony X           19700        6
   4       Samsung Galaxy S8     38000        11
   5            LG G6            31500        12
```

And this is the output in my supplier page

```
   id     productname     quantity
    1        Sony X          10
    2        Sony X          10
    3        Sony X          10
    4        Sony X          10
```

And this is at the order page

```
id     productname     quantity
1        Sony X           10
2        Sony X           5
```

The output now is this:

```
productid     productname        price     quantity      
   6            Sony X           19700        26
   4       Samsung Galaxy S8     38000        11
   5            LG G6            31500        12
```

If youll do the math Sony X should be:

```
productid     productname        price     quantity      
   6            Sony X           19700        31
   4       Samsung Galaxy S8     38000        11
   5            LG G6            31500        12
```

My question is the value of the quantity is not reliable just like in the example,
I have Sony X 6pcs in my stock.
I order a total of 40pcs.
and the customer order a total of 15pcs
It should be 31 left since 6+40=46-15=31
But it shows 26 in my database.

Comment: I'm sorry but, what is the question?

Comment: so you wnt to show all rows ?

Comment: I hope you understand my question. thanks

Comment: TL;DR see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If we break your query down we can see what is happening.

```
drop table if exists p;

create table p (productid int,    productname varchar(20),       price int,    quantity int);
insert into p values     
(   6 ,           'Sony X'         ,  19700 ,       6),
(   4 ,      'Samsung Galaxy S8'   ,  38000 ,      11),
(   5 ,           'LG G6'          ,  31500 ,       12);

drop table if exists s;
create table s (id int,    productname varchar(20),     quantity int);
insert into s values
(    1 ,       'Sony X'  ,        10),
(    2 ,       'Sony X'  ,        10),
(    3 ,       'Sony X'  ,        10),
(    4 ,       'Sony X'  ,        10);

drop table if exists o;
create table o(id  int,   productname varchar(20),     quantity int);
insert into o values
(1 ,       'Sony X'   ,        10),
(2 ,       'Sony X'   ,        5);

MariaDB [sandbox]> select p.productid, p.productname,p.price,
    -> p.quantity
    -> ,ifnull(sum(s.quantity),0) squantity
    -> ,ifnull(sum(o.quantity),0) oquantity
    -> from  p
    -> left join s on p.productname = s.productname
    -> left join o on p.productname = o.productname
    -> group by p.productname
    -> order by quantity
    -> ;
+-----------+-------------------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| productid | productname       | price | quantity | squantity | oquantity |
+-----------+-------------------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|         6 | Sony X            | 19700 |        6 |        80 |        60 |
|         4 | Samsung Galaxy S8 | 38000 |       11 |         0 |         0 |
|         5 | LG G6             | 31500 |       12 |         0 |         0 |
+-----------+-------------------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You could try this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select p.productid,p.productname,p.price,p.quantity, s.*,o.*,p.quantity + ifnull(squantity,0) - ifnull(oquantity,0) qty
    -> from p
    -> left join
    -> (select s.productname sproductname, sum(s.quantity) squantity from s group by s.productname) s on sproductname = p.productname
    -> left join
    -> (select o.productname oproductname, sum(o.quantity) oquantity from o group by o.productname) o on oproductname = p.productname;
+-----------+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+------+
| productid | productname       | price | quantity | sproductname | squantity | oproductname | oquantity | qty  |
+-----------+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+------+
|         6 | Sony X            | 19700 |        6 | Sony X       |        40 | Sony X       |        15 |   31 |
|         4 | Samsung Galaxy S8 | 38000 |       11 | NULL         |      NULL | NULL         |      NULL |   11 |
|         5 | LG G6             | 31500 |       12 | NULL         |      NULL | NULL         |      NULL |   12 |
+-----------+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I just have a question. where did squantity60 and oquantity80 came from?

Comment: If you looked at the joins individually you would get 4 rows returned by the first join and 2 by the second. In tandem you get  8 rows. 8* 10 = 80, (4*10) + (4*5) = 60.